# What size would a planet have to be such that I could throw a tennis ball into orbit?

Tags: planets, hard-science

If I was affixed to the surface of some solid spherical body in space (so as to ignore effects like me floating away), would it be possible for me to throw a tennis ball so that it went into orbit around the body?

I imagine the average density would be an  important variable since I can only throw a tennis ball so hard.

I think, if the density was right, there would be some radius R of this spherical body such that I could throw a tennis ball and it would go into orbit around this sphere.

For the average peson, what would the density and radius be of a sphere such that you could toss a tennis ball and it would go into orbit around this sphere?

Comment: Need to know how much atmosphere you have to push through and if there are limits to your speed you can throw.  Also, how high in orbit, like geosync orbit? You ask for hard science, but the problem is you said "I", so a human, a human needs Earth or Earth like, which means a human can never do this on Earth.  So the size of the planet is "small enough that the person suffocates and dies but large enough to generate some gravity"

Comment: I should have said...no atmosphere. I'm more interested in the size/density of this sphere rather than issues like pushing through atmosphere. I'm also not excluding any orbit...just whatever would be possible. Ignore effects like breathing etc. This is simply an imaginary experiment testing the density/dimensions such that a tennis ball could be thrown into orbit by a human adult.

Comment: It is hardly a planet and density is reflection of composition and structure of that asteroid. We could start building mostly hollow ones for bigger R. But here rises question will our numbers reflect your story world.

Comment: You can not, it'll fall back down or fly away, unless orbit height = your height, but then it'll only fly once and hit you on the back of your head. Otherwise you need two impulses to get an orbit. Would calculations for orbit radius equal to the planet radius + 1.8m satisfy your needs?

Comment: This answer is relatively the same as this one, https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/215997/what-is-the-smallest-item-for-which-gravity-has-been-recorded-or-observed  Since all your need is any gravity at all for an orbit.  I guess in theory your own body could be the source of the gravity and you throw the ball to orbit yourself?

Comment: Obligatory XKCD: https://xkcd.com/681/. Note though as Mołot said, it is referencing escape velocities. If you are ok though with throwing it from a tower or something and having it orbit really low to the ground, check out the stats for Phobos.

Comment: Hardest question at the moment - how fast you can throw a tennis ball... Can someone tell me speed of an average man's throw for a that ball?

Comment: This would probably fit better on Physics.SE.  The boring answer is "yes absolutely, for any speed of throw," though you may be sad at the physics definition of being in orbit. (As Mołot said, you'll hit the back of your own head)  The longer answer is "Take a look at wikipedia's page on [Orbital speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_speed#Tangential_velocities_at_altitude)"  The longer-longer answers involving specifics are the kinds of things that Physics.SE is good at providing.  They might explore interesting questions like eliptical orbits rather than merely circular ones.

Comment: If no one answers this by the end of the day I might give it a go, but you should be able to figure it out if you google it. It should be pretty simple maths. Gravity is proportional to density and distance, and the speed you throw a ball needs to be fast enough that the drop over a period of time is equal to the surface curving away. Of course you ignore things like friction and the atmosphere and assuming you throw it perfectly horizontally.

Comment: Try science-based tag instead of hard-science, hard science != hard-scify. You formulation definitely is not up to hs atm and you do not need that in the case

Comment: ATTENTION VTCers! (a) This is a mathematics problem, the [tag:hard-science] tag can be reasonably applied. Think, "given Earth density, at what radius is the escape velocity equal to average throwing velocity of the human arm?" (b) We're not talking about a planet, we're talking about a planetoid, maybe even an asteroid. It'll be *small.* So stop worrying about things like atmosphere. I do not believe this question is unclear. However, I do wonder what rule of the OP's world the OP is asking about.  Lord Null, why are you asking this quesiton here?  How will this apply to your fictional world?

Comment: @Mołot an orbit at shoulder-to-head height of a thrown object around an asteroid is a key plot element in round two of the first duel between Hector and Odal in "The Duelling Machine" by Ben Bova.  The key is that one party realises that the thrown object is in an orbit and the thrower doesn't - until the object completes its first and only orbit...  Now I want to crunch the maths on that scenario

Comment: @JBH Earth density is too high as the Earth's mass has compressed the center somewhat.

Comment: @LorenPechtel, you must have misunderstood something.  At earth density (5.51 g/cm³), a planetoid the size of a basketball (mass approx. 39 Kg) would require an escape velocity Ve = sqrt(2Gm/r) = 0.002 m/s.  In fact, it would be very hard not to launch it out of orbit.  Density simply modifies the radius of the planetoid given a mass.  If you assume a gentle 25 m/s (a gentle fast-pitch speed), then it's just math to find the radius of the planetoid, which will be bigger than a basketball.

Comment: @JBH I"m not objecting to your math, but your assumption of density.  Earth is denser than a similar mix of materials in an asteroid would be.

Comment: Even more obligatory xkcd what-if: https://what-if.xkcd.com/68/

Answer (score 11):

When the hardest part to give my petty answer is finding out how fast an average person can throw a tennis ball, people serve them mostly. If you throw it is probably somewhere in 80-120 km/h range. Fastballs of pro's in baseball are 150-170 km/h, serves in tennis are close to the same number only in miles per hour.

There is an infinite number of orbits = orbit velocities your tennis ball can go at, from circle to elliptical ones, till you hit escape velocity and then you have a chance at murdering some innocent alien few million years in the future.

- **Circular orbit velocity**: [image: **V**(*orbit*)=SQRT(G*M/R)]; [image];
- **Escape velocity**: [image] or [image];

G - gravitational constant [image]; M - mass of both objects or mass of the planet in our case; R - distance between centers of gravity; g - gravitational acceleration aka. surface gravity.

***Table with some fast calculations***

[image]

So **30-50 km radius** for my speeds of 80-120 km per hour. Density used is what you would expect of a nonmetallic asteroid, but a rocky one at least.

Of course, you could make a tennis ball orbit any asteroid with smaller values, just don't throw it too fast or it will escape. You can even let the tennis ball orbit you if you are okay to wait for something around the magnitude of 1-3 months for a revolution or way more if the radius is bigger.

You can increase it by using a hollowed/altered asteroid, you can play with new mass and radius. How big you could build it before it collapses? That is a big question of itself. Just find what asteroid fulfills requirements of your story and then tweak it for this stunt.

Comment: This is a bounty-worthy answer.